# How to compile multiple csv files into a single xlsx file using R?

Tags: r

Say I have many csv files in a directory called `Path`:

```
abc.csv
def.csv
xyz.csv
```

How can I compile these files into a single xlsx file where each csv becomes its own tab? I've tried using the below function but unfortunately only the first csv ultimately appears in the xlsx:

```
path <- "Path"
filenames_list <- list.files(path = path, full.names = TRUE)

for (i in 1:length(filenames_list)) {

  sheet_name <- strsplit(strsplit(filenames_list[i], "/")[[1]][4], "\\.")[[1]][1]
  file_name <- paste0('Path/output.xlsx')
  temp <- read.csv(filenames_list[i])
  write.xlsx(temp, file = file_name, sheetName = sheet_name, row.names = F, append = T)

}
```

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(openxlsx)
library(tidyverse)

# Make sure your working directory is set to the location where your .csv files are

list.files(pattern = "*.csv") %>% 
  map(., ~read_csv(.)) %>% 
  write.xlsx(., "My Multi-tabbed File.xlsx")
```

Comment: This is great. Is there an easy way to name each tab after its csv file name?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this approach with `sapply` -

```
path <- "Path"
filenames_list <- list.files(path = path, full.names = TRUE)

list_files <- sapply(filenames_list, read.csv, simplify = FALSE)
names(list_files) <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(names(list_files)))

writexl::write_xlsx(list_files, 'data.xlsx')
```